# Representations of Galois groups of structured ring spectra and topological automorphic forms

Tags: homotopy-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Rognes and Mathew have defined Galois groups for certain structured ring spectra ($E_\infty$-ring spectra and axiomatic stable homotopy theories resp.)

Is a connection expected between representations of these Galois groups and the theories of topological modular forms (tmf) and topological automorphic forms, along the lines of Langlands programs, arithmetic and geometric?

Comment: Not sure what sort of connection you want. These Galois groups say more about covers of the associated ring spectra; for instance, the Galois group of TMF is the same as the etale fundamental group of the moduli of elliptic curves (trivial over Z). The Langlands program is more concerned with understanding the absolute Galois groups of fields.